# Display notification on website?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Can we display notification on website dashboard when the product is created from mobile app? I am using laravel 5.1 framework. And i have gone through events listener or broadcasting events but still not convinced. Can any body help me or guide me what i wanted?

For example, a dealer can access the mobile app login and can order some products. And when he order product from mobile app, we need to display notification in website notification section.

Comment: You will need to go into more depth for anyone to be sure that what describing can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel proper support for notifications in their framework. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications

There are some channels supported by Laravel itself and many more by the community.

I think you are looking for Database Notifications (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#database-notifications)

Since you are using 5.1 have a look at this backport (http://laravel-notification-channels.com/backport/)

Comment: but i am using laravel 5.1 stable version. what options should i take ?

Comment: thanks for your good suggestion but still i am unable to use that too. i am kind of beginner in this stuff. can you provide me a blog where it has shown step by step?i want to use database as notification delivery channels

Comment: i kind of got notification to work out. But how i can send the notification to user admin only. I mean can we change or cutomize the notifiable_id while saving in database ?

Comment: You can use User::find($id)->notify(new MyNotification());